# Dropdown list size with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, zurb-foundation, dropdown, cakephp-2.7

I am currently using CakePHP and I have a dropdown list that contains a lot of text. This is actually a list of predefined messages that the user can select.

I wonder if there is a way to tell CakePHP to keep the original size of the dropdown list to not allow text spans to the right, force a carriage return somehow.

I also use Foundation, can be a solution at this level too?

Thanks

Comment: are you asking for width of select box ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add class or Id to that select box and apply css on that to control width of that box like:

```
$options = array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female');
echo $this->Form->select('gender', $options, array('escape' => false));
```

Which will look like

```
<select name="data[User][gender]" id="UserGender">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="M">Male</option>
<option value="F">Female</option>
</select>
```

then add css like

```
#UserGender {width : 200px;}
```

Comment: So I have to set the width directly, thanks for your reply !